# Angular JS tracking between $resource action and return $promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise, angular-resource

I have a grid of various cells where users can drag and drop images into. When dropped on the grid a $resource action call is made and the app is updated.

What I want to achieve is to have a loader in each cell when the update call is active. EG the user drops an item in the cell and a spinning loader is displayed. Once the call is returned the loader is removed from the cell and the cell updated.

All cells run the same call where the data passed to the call is different. My issue is how to track the cell which the return is mapped to. Using this feature users can have multiple cells loading at one time. Of course if everything works fine the results from the call can return the cell location and that can be used to remove the loader. EG an item is dropped, the call is made, the call returns the data which includes the cell location, JS then uses the cell location data to remove the loader and update the cell.

My issue is what happens if it completely fails (for what ever reason). How does the app know which cell to remove the loader from. EG An item is dropped on a cell and a call is made. A is loader displayed in the cell and the app awaits the return. Lets say the return never comes or the return complete errors out. How does it know which cell the failed call belongs to?

What I'm looking for is a way to specify data in the $resource call that can be access in the promise response. EG

```
rest = $resource('www.api-source.com/layout/34/cells','post',{cell_locaiton:'2x4'},{'post': {method:'GET', isArray: false}});
rest.setTracker('2x5');
rest.post( );     

rest.$promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.removeLoader(data.cell_data.location);
},function(data, status, headers, config) {
   cell = rest.getTracker( );
   $scope.removeLoader(cell);
}
```

Where a value is set in the $resource and then extracted from the $promise. I'm not saying this is the best way to do this.
I just want to be able to remove the loader if the cell location data is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why I failed to see this before but it was solved using the $promise.finally( ) callback. This was able to take the data I needed and use it to clear the loader whether the call failed or not.

```
cell = '2x4';
rest = $resource('www.api-source.com/layout/34/cells','post',{cell_locaiton:cell},{'post': {method:'GET', isArray: false}}).post( );     

rest.$promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.removeLoader(cell);
},function(data, status, headers, config) {
   $scope.throwError('Fail');       
}).finally(function(){
   $scope.removeLoader(cell); 
});
```